# Create Taxonomy vocabularies and terms in installation profile

Tags: taxonomy-terms, installation-profiles

I'm creating a Drupal installation profile(drupal 6) and want to create taxonomy vocabularies and terms. How to create taxonomy vocabularies and terms in installation profile?

Answer (score 1):

'Terms' are data, so you must import them using the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module or [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module.

It's easy to create 'vocabularies', not programmatically but using a [Feature](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) and then enable it with you installation profile.

But if you want programmatically [here](http://www.webomelette.com/taxonomy-vocabulary-term-programatically-drupal-7) is a good article that describes how to create Taxonomies vocabularies and terms programmatically.